# Return value of a callback function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, return-value

I have this code:

```
function dialogTexts(message) {
        var langText = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/index.php/main/dialogtexts',
            dataType: 'json'
        });

        langText.done(function(data) {   
            message(data);
        });                        

        langText.fail(function(ts) {
            alert(ts.responseText);
        });
    }

    dialogTexts(function(text) {
        alert(text.delete);         
    });
```

I'm using a callback to alert the string text.delete (in above code), but I want to do something like:

```
dialogTexts(function(text) {
    return text;
});

var deleteConfirmationDialogText = dialogTexts.delete;
alert(deleteConfirmationDialogText); //deleteConfirmationDialogText is undefined
```

Comment: I feel like the "why can't I access data outside of callback"-questions are the most common ones on SO right now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dialogTexts` is a function and it does not have a property `.delete`.  That's why `dialogTexts.delete` is `undefined` when you try to use it.  You simply can't use the kind of shortcut you're trying to do.

---

Also, the return statement in here:

```
dialogTexts(function(text) {
    return text;
});
```

is doing nothing.  It's just returning to the caller of that callback which is inside of `dialogTexts()` and that caller is not doing anything with the return value so `return text` is doing nothing.

If you want to alert the text, you will have to do what you first had:

```
dialogTexts(function(text) {
    alert(text.delete);         
});
```

That is the only real way to do it and this is a consequence of how asynchronous programming works with AJAX calls.  There are some other techniques for handling callbacks (such as promises), but they all require you to process the asynchronously returned data in a callback function.  That's just the nature of asynchronous programming.

Comment: I'm aware that the code does not work, I was look for an answer how I should I achieve what I want :-) Please, can you point me in right direction?

Comment: Ok, so the way to go is to use promises if I want to achieve what I want?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld - not really.  Promises are just a different way of structuring callbacks.  You still have to put the alert in a callback.